# Write cURL request to .json file

Tags: curl, command-line-interface, parse-server

I want to take the response body generated from this request:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: AppId" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: RESTAPIKey" \
https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/_User
```

...and output a .json file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: AppId" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: RESTAPIKey" \
https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/_User > out.json`

or
`curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: AppId" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: RESTAPIKey" \
https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/_User  -o out.json`

*Edited to add more info:*

The second is probably nicer because it is entirely cURL though the redirect gives you more options if you did want to run it through another script for formatting reasons. I don't think either option will pretty print the json on their own.

Comment: Cool. This worked. Why would you use one over the other? I noticed the second one is not in a single line... Which I guess is better? Is there a way to output this with better formatting, indenting, etc?

Comment: @santafebound I've updated the answer, would have to think about the way to add indentation / formatting.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your answer regardless. I've found that using this service will pretty print the single-line JSON anyway: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. I just validate, format and re-download the file for easier reading.